# Access VBA exporting CSV file as UTF-8

Tags: csv, ms-access, utf-8, vba

I have to export data from Access multiple times a day as a CSV file. The person who had my job before me created this VBA code that exports the data in the click of a button. However, I need to modify it so that it exports as UTF-8 without BOM so that international characters will show up in the software that I import it to.

I can manually export as Text and then save it as CSV, when I go to the "Advanced..." settings I select `Code Page: Unicode (UTF-8)` and this works perfectly. But as I said before, I want to change the VBA code:

```
Private Sub Command6_Click()
Dim sExportPath As String
Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef


With Me.List0
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            sExportPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\final_" & Left(Me.List0.Column(0, i), InStr(Me.List0.Column(0, i), " ") - 1) & ".csv"
            If QueryExists("Final") Then CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "Final"


            Set qry = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Final", "Select Salutation,Email from " & Left(Me.List0.Column(0, i), InStr(Me.List0.Column(0, i), " ") - 1))
            CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Refresh
            DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Final", sExportPath, True

        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the value 65001 as CodePage parameter (the last one of the TransferText method), which is represents Unicode (UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

Perform the export manually and choose "Advanced..." as you did before. After you have chosen the "Code Page" and other settings, click the "Save As..." button to save the export specification. Then you can supply the name of the saved specification as the second argument to the `TransferText` method, e.g.,

```vbs
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "MyExportSpecification", "Final", sExportPath, True
```

Comment: I tried that and got this error: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj681075(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: when I try to export table ZResults1 it says it "could not find the opject 'final_ZResults1.csv'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly"

Comment: Double-check your code. You should not be getting that error for `acExportDelim`. (For `acImportDelim` that error would make sense if the file you were trying to import did not exist.)

Comment: the table is not always going to be called ZResults1, at times it may even be a query I am exporting. is this happening because the ExportSpecification is for ZResults1 and what it's looking for is final_ZResults1 because of the "Final" argument? I've tried multiple things and nothing has worked so far. @Gord

Comment: this is the code: <br /> `DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Final_ZResults1 Export Specification", "Final", sExportPath, True`

Comment: Try double-clicking the saved query named "Final" to see if it will work on its own.

Comment: the query "Final" does work. when I applied the ExportSpecification steps to "Final" and then inserted that into the second argument you mentioned, it worked. But when i try to export a query or anything besides ZResults1, it doesn't work- I get the same error: it could not find the object

Comment: I have several buttons which all use this same code, the only difference is the select query. Is it not working because it is being reused? I'm trying new things and getting no where